# Why is navParams.data empty when I bind to root page using ion-nav rootParams parameter?

Tags: ionic-framework

I'm trying to bind rootParams to ion-nav so I can switch between pages and set different parameters.

```
<ion-nav #content [root]="rootPage" [rootParams]="rootParams"></ion-nav>
```

So when I change page and rootParams in app.component.ts, the parameters will be passed to the new root page.

```
this.rootPage = 'HomePage';
this.rootParams = { value: 1 };
```

However in the constructor of the page, navParams has no value

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
    const value = this.navParams.data.value;//undefined
}
```

Any ideas how to pass parameters to root pages?

Comment: this is ionic v3?

Comment: its directly `const value = this.navParams.data;`

Answer (score 0):

I also not too many knowledge about NavController and NavParams, so I defined one service use for leave this question. One simple example here:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject, Subscription } from 'rxjs';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SiteService {
    public rootParams;
    public rootParamsSubject: Subject<Object> = new Subject<Object>();
    constructor() {
        //restore root parameters from localStage or others
        ...
        //and subscribe the subject, you also can subscribe it at your main component
        this.rootParamsSubject.subscribe(data => {
            Object.assign(this.rootParams, data);
        });
    }
}
/*At any others
class ... {
    constructor(private siteService: SiteService)
    function ... {
        if nav params
        this.siteService.rootParamsSubject.next(navParams.data);
        then all subscriber both know it.
    }
}*/
```